# onchange check password to be similar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have created a small fields for checking password to be similar like while writing confirm password it should verify whether the confirm password is similar or not I have created but it is not working can somebody help me out with this please.

My code:

```js
function ppd() {
  var password = $("#password").val();
  var confirm_password = $("#confirm").val();

  if (password != confirm_password) {
    $("#confirm").css('border-color', "#c80000");
    $("#textboxid").css({
      "background-color": "#fee2e2"
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" id="password" name="" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" id="confirm" onChange="ppd();" name="" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

`jQuery` Fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/fthsv936/)

Comment: Removed the `java` tag since this question has nothing to do with Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger `onkeyup` event handler.The event is triggered after the character is typed into the form field.

Here is solution.

```js
document.getElementById('confirm').onkeyup=function(){
    var password = $("#password").val();
 var confirm_password = $("#confirm").val();
 if(password != confirm_password) {
           $("#confirm").css('border-color', "red");
 }
        else{
           $("#confirm").css('border-color', "green");
        }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
     <input type="password" id="password" name="" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" />
</div>
      
<div class="form-group">
 <input type="password" id="confirm"  name="" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Another solution is to use `oninput` method.

```
document.getElementById('confirm').oninput=function(){
  //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code on your given fiddle. There is nothing wrong in it except lastline as you have not div with this id.

```
    $("#textboxid").css({"background-color": "#fee2e2"});
```

Your code is absolutely correct and it is better to use onchange in this scenario. Just you have to understand how onchange works here. The onchange event is fired when the element loses the focus and the contents have changed since the last time the element got the focus.

I dont know what's wrong there, may be jquery file is not working or else.
This code is working.

```
    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" id="confirm" onChange="ppd();" name="" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
```

Javascript

```
function ppd(){ 
var password         = $("#password").val();
var confirm_password = $("#confirm").val();

if(password != confirm_password) {
    $("#confirm").css({'border-color': "#c33"});
    $("#password").css({"background-color": "red"});
```

}
}

I giving you link of my codepen with your own code.[check here](http://codepen.io/mupadhyay00/pen/zoJddJ?editors=1010)